# Java split string with blank delimiter

Tags: java, string, split, line

I have a string witch i want to split. The only delimiter that i have it's a blank space. Looks like this:
12 BobMarley 22/01/15 0 0 1 1 0

and I use this:

```
line = br1.readLine();
String[] parts = line.split(" ");
String number    = parts[0]; 
String reference = parts[1]; 
String date      = parts[2];
String one       = parts[3];
String sd        = parts[4];
String dd        = parts[5];
String tt        = parts[6];
String vs        = parts[7];
System.out.println(
 "No:"+number+"Ref:"+reference+"Date:"+date+"One:"+one+"Sd:"+sd+"Dd:"+dd+"Tt:"+tt+"Vs:"+vs);
```

The result is:

No:12 Ref:BobMarley Date:22/01/15 One:0 Sd:0 Dd:1 Tt:1 Vs:0

as expected. All OK.

Now, my problem is when the string is : 12 **Bob Marley** 22/01/15 0 0 1 1 0

or: 12 Harry Potter And The Band 22/01/15 0 0 1 1 0

The output will be:

No:12 **Ref:Bob Date:Marley** One:22/01/15 Sd0 Dd:0 Tt:1 Vs:1

expected: 12 Ref:Bob Marley Date:22/01/15 ........

Any idea how can I trim only the white spaces between the "No." and the "Date"? Or any other idea how to get a clean "Ref" no matter how many words are inside. Thank you!

Comment: Any reason to not replace the space delimiter with a comma instead?

Comment: I cannot modify the input. The string is one of the lines from a text file created reading a .PDF. The PDF is a "table" that I want to convert it in a tableModel and create a jTable from the "PDF table".

Comment: Just a stupid solution if you don't want to use regexes and if the problem is only the one you described: split at spaces, as soon as you read `date` check out if it's a valid date. If not, append all the `date` text to `reference`, otherwise just read the date and go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to split the line using regex at first to catch the reference part then split using space to get the result:

```
String line = "12 Bob Marley 22/01/15 0 0 1 1 0";

    String pattern = "([0-9]+)([a-zA-z|' ']+)(.*)";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("No:" + m.group(1));//this will get 12
        System.out.println("ref:" + m.group(2));//this will get the name
        String[] parts = m.group(3).split(" ");//this is the rest
        String date      = parts[0];
        String one       = parts[1];
        String sd        = parts[2];
        String dd        = parts[3];
        String tt        = parts[4];
        String vs        = parts[5];
        System.out.println("Date:"+date+"One:"+one+"Sd:"+sd+"Dd:"+dd+"Tt:"+tt+"Vs:"+vs);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the greatest at regex, but here's what I got:

```
/(\d+) ([\w ]+) (\d+\/\d+\/\d+) (\d) (\d) (\d) (\d) (\d)/
```

It matches

- any number of digits, followed by a space and
- any amount of letters and spaces, followed by a space and
- `digits/digits/digits`, followed by a space and
- digit, space
- digit, space
- digit, space
- digit, space
- digit

http://regexr.com/3cqrj

---

Or, to make things easier for everybody, separate your values with, say, commas. They're made for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is a generally good practice to choose a delimiter that is not a common symbol in values. For example choosing a blank space as a delimiter causes problems with a single value that contains blank spaces.

If you can change the contract of the data storage in the file, I suggest you chose a different delimiter - for example a comma.

If you have no other choice but using a blank space as a delimiter, then your only option is to hardcode the partitioning of the file by using some kind of regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Find index of where the date appears. Simple version  using `s.indexOf("/")` and decide if it is two digit day or not

You can also use patterns to do this

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
startDateIdx = matcher.start();

endNumberIdx = s.indexOf(" ");

String number    = s.substring(0,endNumberIdx-1); 
String reference = s.substring(endNumberIdx+1,startDateIdx-1); 
String[] parts   = s.subtring(startDateIdx).split(" ");
String date      = parts[0];
String one       = parts[1];
String sd        = parts[2];
String dd        = parts[3];
String tt        = parts[4];
String vs        = parts[5];
```